# Fast ping function for PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a fast function for pinging a list of machines using PowerShell?

I know I can use Test-Connection:

```
Test-Connection -Count 1 -ComputerName (gc .\comps.txt) -ea silentlycontinue
```

but this seems painfully slow (I'm assuming because it uses Win32_PingStatus).

Even better would be an example of how running it as a background job to speed it up would be most useful.

Comment: Are you on powershell v1 or v2? (v2 banner copyright date is 2009)

Comment: I'm on v2.  I thought Test-Connection was only in v2?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97726/powershell-to-quickly-ping-a-number-of-machines

Comment: I was looking for a fast ping sweeper and came across this question.  I settled on this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Fast-asynchronous-ping-IP-d0a5cf0e/

Answer (score 5):

The PowerShell Community Extensions include a fast ping (among other useful scripts and aliases)

http://pscx.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is the one I use.  It allows you to specify the timeout value.

Comment: The Command is:
Ping-Host [-HostName] <PSObject[]> [[-Count] <Int32>] [-NoDnsResolution] [-Quiet] [[-BufferSize] <Int32>] [[-Timeout] <Int32>] [[-TTL] <Int32>] [[-AllAddresses]] [[-Asynchronous]] [<Common Parameters>]

Comment: This was apparently a solution for PowerShell 1.0.  The `Ping-host` cmdlet is now deprecated by the author and is replaced by `test-connection`.  if you go through the trouble of installing PSCX anyways, you will get an error every time you use it.